# How to wrapper an object in an interface?

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection

I have the interface

```
public interface ICallFlowApplication
{
    void HandleCall();
}
```

And the implementation

```
 public class TestCallFlowApplication : ICallFlowApplication
 {
    public void HandleCall()
    {
        // blah blah
```

Now for some reason, I need to pass an object to the method, so that

```
    public void HandleCall(SipChannel channel)
    {
```

I think that I have to refactor the interface `ICallFlowApplication` as

```
public interface ICallFlowApplication
{
    void HandleCall(SipChannel channel);
}
```

But SipChannel is a special channel. There are different channels. I want to use dependency injection here.
My questions:

1. How to rewrite my interface `ICallFlowApplication`?
2. Do I need to create a new interface such as `IChannel`?
3. If so, what is the details in side it?(sample code)

Comment: are all the "Channel" inherit any class or implement any interface?

Comment: We don't know yet. We will get the different channels from the different vendors. But there is a channel for each vendor product.

Comment: if "channels" are not controlled by you. even if you defined an interface, might be difficult to ask all vendors to implement the same interface (if you can talk them in, it will be ideal). work-around will be take in an object instead of a specific type. and use a factory class to figure out the right type.

Comment: Why down vote? It is not an elemental school problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use generics -

```
    public interface ICallFlowApplication<T> where T : IChannel
    {
        void HandleCall(T channel);
    }

    public class TestCallFlowApplication : ICallFlowApplication<SipChannel>
    {
       public void HandleCall(SipChannel channel){}
    }

    public class SipChannel : IChannel {}
    public interface IChannel {}
```

Here is an example of wrapping SipChannel in your own object and inheriting from IChannel --

```
    public interface ICallFlowApplication<T> where T : IChannel
    {
        void HandleCall(T channel);
    }

    public class TestCallFlowApplication : ICallFlowApplication<MySipChannel>
    {
        public void HandleCall(MySipChannel channel){}
    }

    public class MySipChannel : IChannel 
    {
        private SipChannel _channel;

        public MySipChannel(SipChannel channel)
        {
            _channel = channel;
        }

        // expose methods/properties you need
    }

    public interface IChannel {}
    public class SipChannel {} // declared in some unknown dll
```

Comment: So the interface `IChannel` is empty?

Comment: The Interface IChannel can have whatever it needs. In this case, it is empty because I do not know your requirements.

Comment: Are you defining the IChannel implementations in your code? (e.g. SipChannel) Or is that provided via a 3rd party dll? If the latter, then you will need to use a proxy rather than an interface.

Comment: The thing is I know `SipChannel` from the third party, I have the framework for it.

Comment: To keep things simple and give you the most control, I think your best bet is to wrap SipChannel in your own object that inherits from IChannel. Expose whatever fields/methods you need and use the new object in your class declaration.

Comment: I want to use dependency injection. Say something like `HandleCall(IChannel channel)`.

Comment: If you don't want to use generics, then you can use an interface or even `object` and type-cast to the appropriate object type inside your HandleCall method but that is not the best approach.

Comment: I need more information on how you store `ICallFlowApplication`s and how you call `HandleCall` to be able to give you a better example. Dependency injection is typically done via a constructor when you instantiate an object. Not when you call some method with a generic/base type.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, which might or might not suit your needs.

As Tom A. said, your best bet is to create an `IChannel` interface, and wrap that around the channels provided by third parties. If you have to do something with these channels, you can specify it in your interface, and implement it separately for each channel depending on the specifics from each vendor.

```
public interface IChannel
{
    void DoSomething();
    string DoSomethingElse();
}

public class SipChannel : IChannel
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //go do some stuff
    }

    public string DoSomethingElse()
    {
        return "I did some stuff for you.";
    }
}

public OtherChannel : IChannel
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //go do some stuff
    }

    public string DoSomethingElse()
    {
        return "I'm not sure what this one does yet.";
    }
}
```

So now, `HandleCall` can have the signature: `void HandleCall(IChannel channel);`

and be implemented something like this:

```
public void HandleCall(IChannel channel)
{
    channel.DoSomething();
    channel.DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Which will call the implementation of the specific instance you pass in.